# Viewport meta tag for fixed width but scaled to device-width

Tags: android, html, mobile, viewport

Our website has two separate versions for mobile and desktop, and our mobile version needs to have a fixed width that is displayed on all devices in the same way. The website is currently using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=750; user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="750">
```

It works for most cases just fine, our mobile version has 750px width and is scaled to the viewport-size of the device and is not scalable. We now found out that on older Android devices it doesn't work (tested until 4.3, maybe later versions are affected, too).

[edit: The problem also only seems to apply to the native Android Browser. Chrome displays it correctly.]

The page that loads has 750px width, but is not scaled, so it is too large and doesn't fit and the user only sees a part of the page. It is also scalable, which means the `user-scalable= no` isn't working, either.

(Responsive Layout is not an option for us, btw. We need the mobile page to be exactly 750px wide).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=750px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work unfortunately, it even brings the problem to all devices. I don't want the scale to be 1, because not every device has 750px width.